# Android studio: deploy last built apk to device

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio, is there a way to just deploy the .apk that was last built to a device without running the gradle build again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the "Gradle" tool window, under the "All tasks" pane, there should be an installDebug task which will install the debug build of the APK. There will be similar tasks for other build types (e.g Release) and flavors as well if you have them.